# Partial Mantel test in R vegan package gives error

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, vegan

I'm trying to run Partial Mantel tests using R vegan package. I'm getting the following error in the output even on a very simple dummy data.

My code:

```
  m1 = matrix(c(0, 1, 2,
                1, 0, 3,
                2, 3, 0),nrow = 3)
  m2 = m1 * 2
  m3 = m1 * 3
  mtest = mantel.partial(xdis = m1, ydis = m2,zdis = m3)
  print(mtest)
```

The output:

```
Partial Mantel statistic based on Pearson product-moment correlation 

Call:
mantel.partial(xdis = m1, ydis = m2, zdis = m3) 

Mantel statistic r:   NaN 
      Significance: NA 

Error in quantile.default(x$perm, c(0.9, 0.95, 0.975, 0.99)) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE
```

Comment: Setting 'na.rm' to TRUE in 'mantel.partial()' did't fix the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example matrices are linearly dependent; `m2` is a simple linear transformation of `m1` so they are perfectly correlated. As is `m3`. Once you account for the correlation between one pair of matrices, there is nothing left over to correlate with, hence the weird `NaN`s and `NA`s and the ultimate error.

Comment: All three matrices are linearly dependent, and all correlations coefficients are 1. Partial correlation will be the result of 0/0 which is "Not a Number" (NaN) and correctly reported. Why would somebody want to analyse data like this?

Comment: @Jari Oksanen maybe to learn how to use the library, is this against any rules?. Your comment sir adds no value to this thread. This case should be handled better by the library instead of throwing a runtime error.

Comment: @Hani: it does not throw a runtime error, but gives the result as not-a-number (which is the correct answer). In practice, you can have this kind of results only in specially crafted artificial data and they do not bother people analysing real data. In principle, we could cast `NaN` to some other value, but I have no idea what that value should be (correlation 0 and *P*-value 1 is one choice, but that would also confuse people who think that their data are perfectly correlated).

Comment: @Jari Oksanen "you can have this kind of results only in specially crafted artificial data" This is not entirely true. I first got this error while running my code on a big dataset of different distance matrices. This error kept breaking my data processing loop (during runtime) and wasn't just throwing a message.

Comment: Which "first error"? The post has only one example of three variables, each with three observations and gives no error, but the correct result (not a number). Any other errors are private to you, and I have no idea what you are talking about. If this result breaks a "data processing loop", the error must come from some other function that does not handle its input correctly in the loop, or from some other error in `mantel.partial()`. Use `traceback()` to see which function gave the error and how you ended there.